# Interleaving tf.data.Datasets

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use tf.data.Dataset to interleave two datasets but having problems doing so. Given this simple example:

```
ds0 = tf.data.Dataset()
ds0 = ds0.range(0, 10, 2)
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset()
ds1 = ds1.range(1, 10, 2)
dataset = ...
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
val = iter.get_next()
```

What is `...` to produce an output like `0, 1, 2, 3...9`?

It would seem like dataset.interleave() would be relevant but I haven't been able to formulate the statement in a way that doesn't generate an error.

Comment: You can interleave the values of ds0 and ds1 by calling tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds0, ds1)). But that contains one element for each pair of values. I don't know how to flatten a multi-element dataset into a single-element dataset.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

MattScarpino is on the right track in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343228/interleaving-tf-data-datasets#comment81639602_47343228). You can use [`Dataset.zip()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip) along with [`Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) to flatten a multi-element dataset:

```
ds0 = tf.data.Dataset.range(0, 10, 2)
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10, 2)

# Zip combines an element from each input into a single element, and flat_map
# enables you to map the combined element into two elements, then flattens the
# result.
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds0, ds1)).flat_map(
    lambda x0, x1: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x0).concatenate(
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x1)))

iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
val = iter.get_next()
```

Having said this, your intuition about using [`Dataset.interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) is pretty sensible. We're investigating ways that you can do this more easily.

---

PS. As an alternative, you *can* use `Dataset.interleave()` to solve the problem if you change how `ds0` and `ds1` are defined:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(2).interleave(
    lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.range(x, 10, 2), cycle_length=2, block_length=1)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the quick and complete answer. And thanks to you and team for continuing improvements to TF with the dataset api, etc.

Comment: Reading this in 2020, I guess that `interleave` would really be **the** way to go, right? Can you maybe explain the differences? E.g. which would be more efficient?

Comment: The answer using `interleave` is missing something, isn't it? It doesn't make any use of `ds0` and `ds1`.

Answer (score 5):

[tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets) method could be also useful if you do not need to preserve the strict order for the items you want to interleave.

In my case I had to interleave a real life data with some synthetic data, so the order was not an issue for me. Then this can be easily done as follows

```python
dataset = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([ds0, ds1])
```

Note that the result will be **non-deterministic** and some items could be taken from same dataset twice, but in general it will be very similar to regular interleave.

The advantages of this approach:

- you can use multiple datasets in one method call
- you can specify fraction of the samples for each dataset using `weights` parameter (e.g. I wanted to have only small fraction of the data to be generated so I used `weights=[0.9, 0.1]`)

Answer (score 4):

Pavel's answer works great if you don't mind the order of interleaving. If you *do* care...

#### Option 1

A variant on mrry's answer that works with an arbitrary number of input datasets:

```py
ds0 = tf.data.Dataset.range(0, 10, 3)
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10, 3)
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(2, 10, 3)
datasets = (ds0, ds1, ds2)

# Note: `datasets` should be a *tuple*, not a list.
datasets_zipped = tf.data.Dataset.zip(datasets)
# Each element of the dataset will now be a tuple, e.g. (0, 1, 2).
datasets_zipped_tensor = datasets_zipped.map(lambda *args: tf.stack(args))
# Each element will now be a Tensor, e.g. Tensor([0, 1, 2]).
datasets_interleaved = datasets_zipped_tensor.unbatch()
```

However, note that because of the way `zip` works, the dataset this produces **limited by the length of the shortest input dataset**. For example, using the above code with

```py
datasets = [
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([10, 20]),
)
```

would yield a dataset comprising just `[1, 10, 2, 20]`.

#### Option 2

`Dataset.interleave` doesn't suffer from this problem. In *some* cases you can use `interleave` with:

```py
# Note: `datasets` should be a *list*, not a tuple
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(datasets).interleave(lambda x: x)
```

But this doesn't seem to work for all kinds of dataset; **calling `from_tensor_slices` on your datasets may not work**.

#### Option 3

If option 2 doesn't work, you might be able to use `interleave` at an earlier stage of your dataset pipeline. For example, you might be able to change from calling `interleave` on pre-existing datasets to calling `interleave` on the file names from which the individual datasets were created:

```py
filenames = ['foo', 'bar']
filesnames_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

def read_dataset(filename): ...

interleaved_dataset = filenames_dataset.interleave(read_dataset)
```

But **this will only work if your `read_dataset` function accepts a `Tensor` argument**.

#### Option 4

If none of the other options work for you, I think the only solution is to implement the interleaving yourself, with something like:

```py
element_spec = datasets[0].element_spec
assert all(dataset.element_spec == element_spec for dataset in datasets)

def interleave_generator():
  iters_not_exhausted = [iter(dataset) for dataset in datasets]
  while iters_not_exhausted:
    for dataset_iter in iters_not_exhausted:
      try:
        x = next(dataset_iter)
      except StopIteration:
        iters_not_exhausted.remove(dataset_iter)
      else:
        yield x

datasets_interleaved = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    interleave_generator,
    output_signature=element_spec,
)
```