# How to make two out of one training example in tensorflow dataset using map

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a number of training examples in my dataset and would like to rotate each one so that I get double the number. I am using datasets and tried it like this:

```
def addrotation(images, labels):
  images_rotated_left = tf.contrib.image.rotate(images, pi/2.0)
  labels_rotated_left = tf.stack([labels[1], labels[2], labels[0]])
  return tf.stack([images,images_rotated_left]), tf.stack([labels, labels_rotated_left])
```

But when I now use `dataset = dataset.map(addrotation)`, I get examples with double the data.

Is it possible to return the rotated tensors in a way so that they count as seperate examples or "lines"?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found a solution:
I create a new dataset with all the rotated examples and then zip the two datasets together like explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47344405/984336